Python Pandas how to plot multiple colmuns on x axis?
I have a dataframe that looks like this:
import pandas as pd
data = {'Floor': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'IDR 1': [15, 6, 7, 9], 'IDR 2': [36, 12, 78, 23]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df:
   Floor  IDR 1  IDR 2
0      1     15     36
1      2      6     12
2      3      7     78
3      4      9     23

And I want to plot this dataframe as a line chart where y-axis is the floor. I have read the documentation on df.plot() method and it seem you can input more than one columns of data into y kwarg but not to the x.
So I have been reseaching to find a solution and I came across this question that resemles the most to my problem:
Plotting multiple columns in a pandas line graph
I have this code:
df.plot(kind="line", y=["IDR 1", "IDR 2"], x="Floor", grid=True, xlabel="Floor", ylabel=data)
Basicly I just want to swap the axises.

Code
use loop
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

cols = ['IDR 1', 'IDR 2']

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

for col in cols:
    df.plot(x=col, y='Floor', ax=ax)
    
plt.xlabel('IDR value')
plt.ylabel('Floor')
plt.legend(labels=cols)
plt.show()



import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Sample data
data = {'Floor': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'IDR 1': [15, 6, 7, 9], 'IDR 2': [36, 12, 78, 23]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Columns to plot
cols = ['IDR 1', 'IDR 2']

# Create a figure and axis
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# Plot each column
for col in cols:
    ax.plot(df[col], df['Floor'], marker='o', label=col)

# Set labels and legend
ax.set_xlabel('IDR value')
ax.set_ylabel('Floor')
ax.legend()

# Show the plot
plt.show()


